# Looping through a locally stored video in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, I am trying to have a video playing and looping the whole time within my HTML page. I added the

```html
<video src="img/Pexels Videos 2169880_Trimmed_Trimmed.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
```

autoplay loop within the HTML file and it still isn't looping through the video. Does anyone have any idea of how to loop through this video via JavaScript? I've tried various different functions but none of them have been working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<video id="video" src="img/Pexels Videos 2169880_Trimmed_Trimmed.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
<script>
var video = document.getElementById('video')
// When the 'ended' event fires
video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
  // Reset the video to 0
  video.currentTime = 0;
  // And play again
  video.play();
});
</script>
```

Comment: So I tried a similar function to that and it didn't work. Just tried what you put, and same result, the video pauses when it reaches the end..

Comment: i think it's has something to do with either 
1 - the browser settings , you should try on diffrent one , or
2 - the video file it's self ( where it's doesn't send that the video was eneded try with diffrent video )

and check if the function get triggred add 
video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
  console.log('test')
})

Comment: Yeah I just tried to console log it and nothing popped up. Do you think there could be an issue with the id assignment? Kind of new to javascript so I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this

Comment: Update - fixed it. It was a situation with the video file. Trimmed the same exact video a couple seconds, and it work! Thank you sir

Comment: No problem :) glad it's got fixed